# Halifax long layover, recheck bags?

Tags: luggage, layovers, connecting-flights, yhz, westjet

I've booked a flight with WestJet. I have a 12-hour layover in Halifax, Canada. I'm wondering if i need to collect my bags at the layover and recheck them, or if they will go all the way to Glasgow, Scotland (my final destination). The flights were booked at the same time and are on the same itinerary.

Answer (score 4):

By default your bags will be checked through to Glasgow, unless your Glasgow flight is the following day or you ask for your bags to be short-checked.  In this case, you can pick up your bags in Halifax, Nova Scotia and then re-check them when you return to Halifax Stanfield airport for your second flight.

Answer (score 3):

You have to **ask the airline specifically about this itinerary** as there are several factors involved.

If the connection is *overnight*, there is a distinct probability you will have to collect your bags and recheck the next day.

Comment: WestJet will check the bags through unless the YHZ-GLA flight is the following day, or the passenger asks for them to be short-checked at the originating airport.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie Thanks, but that's exactly what I said???

Comment: You said "distinct possibility"; I'm confirming that it *will* happen in this circumstance.